# Eclipse for Symbian S60 application develpoment

Tags: eclipse, for-loop, symbian

How to create Symbian s60 application using Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Nokia's Carbide.c++ is built using Eclipse, but requires its own full installation.  It's not an Eclipse plugin. Lots of information, including downloads at http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Carbide.c%2B%2B

Answer (score 1):

Installing the SDK for use with Eclipse

To use Eclipse with the SDK, install the applications below  in the following order:

```
Java SE Development Kit (JDK)

Eclipse 3.4.1

Eclipse ME 1.7.9 or  Eclipse Mobile Tools for Java v0.9.1

Series 40 6th Edition SDK
```

for sample example visit the link http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Java/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to use IDE from Nokia's Symbian SDK? This IDE is based on Eclipse.

Comment: Can we program using C++ in this SDK?

Comment: Symbian SDK is not an IDE it's just provides the emulator in order use this we need eclipse as IDE.